# package not found (import com.poiji.annotation.ExcelCellName) after adding poiji dependency in POM

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I am working on a Maven project, and I added poiji dependency (poiji is an API for reading from CSV files), so I added the dependency as recommended:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ozlerhakan</groupId>
    <artifactId>poiji</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

now when I try to do import I get an error saying *package not found*, the imports I'm doing are:

```
import com.poiji.annotation.ExcelCellName;
import com.poiji.annotation.ExcelRow;
```

PS: I am using IntelliJ and after adding the dependencies in POM I did *clean* then *test*.

Comment: Have you run "Reload" from Maven tool window? Also please try to run "File | Invalidate Caches".

Comment: Did you happen to upgrade to the 2021.1 version recently?

Comment: the problem solved , I only had to close intellij and reopen it again! lol
and yes I have already the latest version of intellij